# How do I create a list of phone numbers for people whose reference numbers appear in two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I have two sets of data in columns A & B and also in columns C & D. Some of the content in column C & D does not appear in columns A & B:

`A = reference numbers`
`00001, 00002, 00003, 00004`

`B = phone numbers for column a people`
`123456789, 234567890, 345678901, 456789012`

`C = reference numbers` (these contain SOME of the reference numbers that appear in column A)
`00001, 00002, 00004`
(NOTE: 00003 is missing)

`D = phone numbers for column C people` (these contain SOME of the phone numbers that appear in column B)
`123456789, 234567890, 456789012`
(NOTE: the phone number 345678901 is missing)

How would I create a separate column that contains the phone number from column B of anyone whose reference numbers appear anywhere in **BOTH** columns A and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column E, enter `=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,C1),B1,"")`. Then drag this formula down as far as you need.

What this is doing is counting the instances of the reference number in column `C` against the entire column `A`. If it finds one or more instances, it outputs the phone number found in column `D`, else it displays a blank.

You can then apply a filter on column `E`, uncheck blanks, copy the column, remove filter and paste in column `F` to get a continuous list without blanks (and after this can safely delete column `E`).

Comment: The way I read the question, it sounds like they want the result to be both `B` & `D` phone numbers together.

Comment: I had thought of that possibility, but in the example they give, the phone numbers correspond to the reference numbers. So I assume ref 0001 will have the same phone number in either column `B` or `D`. But if it is the other way around Simon, please comment :) Also mention how you would like the two numbers split, i.e. comma, or space, etc

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help so far.  To clarify, a person will have the same phone number and reference number in columns B and D.  If the reference number appears in both columns A and C, then we just need the phone number that appears in column B to appear in a new column.

Comment: Ok, so my original formula stands, but made an edit to the answer to change the `D1` to `B1`. Though it should not make a difference according to your rules.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. The next challenge is how would I be able to expand this formula on another spreadsheet with the same columns? On this one, I would like to do all the above (so i'm using the =IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,C1),B1,"") formula) I would like to add fields to Column E so that it also lists the telephone number that appears in Column B of any person's reference number (e.g. 00005) that appears in Column C but does not appear in Column A?

Comment: @Simon, I'm not sure whether this new situation is clear. You have phone numbers in column B without reference numbers in column A? Maybe posting a new question would be appropriate.